# How can I sum a particular column and group as a row in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-quicksight, datagrip

I am looking for a SQL statement to sum all of the values in a particular column, and create a row with the name of that column and the summed values. This is very easy to do in Excel, however I have been struggling to do this in SQL. I have been doing a lot of research but can't seem to find any resources to solve this issue.

The reason I am doing this is to get my 'original data set' (first screenshot below) into a format I can create a funnel visual with in AWS QuickSight (needs to be in a format shown in second screenshot below to create the funnel). Not sure why it is so difficult to create a funnel visual in QuickSight. It is very easy to do in Power BI.

Please see example below:

I have data in this format that I've queried via DataGrip, my original data set:

[original data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvcGj.png)

And I want to summarize into this table within SQL (each row will be a level within the funnel):

[new data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2lwY.png)

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Comment: An usual SQL query to do this will be "SELECT SUM(form_submit) AS form_submit, SUM(banner_click) AS banner_click, SUM(conversion) AS conversion FROM dataset". I don't know anything about amazon-quicksight, but maybe this helps.

Comment: Do unions typically take a long time? A coworker of mine shared her query that is similar to what I'm trying to get to, but it took almost 20minutes to run. I need to cut down on that time, so I'm trying to get around that.
Thanks, Jonas! I will try this one out.

Answer (score -1):

you could use **pivot**. for example we have table like this below:

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Orders
(
  orderid   INT        NOT NULL,
  orderdate DATE       NOT NULL,
  empid     INT        NOT NULL,
  custid    VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  qty       INT        NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Orders PRIMARY KEY(orderid)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Orders(orderid, orderdate, empid, custid, qty)
VALUES
  (30001, '20140802', 3, 'A', 10),
  (10001, '20141224', 2, 'A', 12),
  (10005, '20141224', 1, 'B', 20),
  (40001, '20150109', 2, 'A', 40),
  (10006, '20150118', 1, 'C', 14),
  (20001, '20150212', 2, 'B', 12),
  (40005, '20160212', 3, 'A', 10),
  (20002, '20160216', 1, 'C', 20),
  (30003, '20160418', 2, 'B', 15),
  (30004, '20140418', 3, 'C', 22),
  (30007, '20160907', 3, 'D', 30);
```

if you select table you have this:

```
orderid orderdate   empid   custid  qty
10001   2014-12-24  2       A       12
10005   2014-12-24  1       B       20
10006   2015-01-18  1       C       14
20001   2015-02-12  2       B       12
20002   2016-02-16  1       C       20
30001   2014-08-02  3       A       10
30003   2016-04-18  2       B       15
30004   2014-04-18  3       C       22
30007   2016-09-07  3       D       30
40001   2015-01-09  2       A       40
40005   2016-02-12  3       A       10
```

we can use this query:

```
SELECT empid,
  SUM(qty) AS TotalQty,
  SUM(CASE WHEN custid = 'A' THEN qty END) AS A,
  SUM(CASE WHEN custid = 'B' THEN qty END) AS B,
  SUM(CASE WHEN custid = 'C' THEN qty END) AS C,
  SUM(CASE WHEN custid = 'D' THEN qty END) AS D  
FROM dbo.Orders
GROUP BY empid;
```

result for this query is:

```
empid   TotalQty    A       B       C       D
1       54          NULL    20      34      NULL
2       79          52      27      NULL    NULL
3       72          20      NULL    22      30
```

but better solution is use Pivot:

```
SELECT empid, A, B, C, D
FROM (SELECT empid, custid, qty
      FROM dbo.Orders) AS D
PIVOT(SUM(qty) FOR custid IN(A, B, C, D)) AS P;
```

result for this query is:

```
empid   A       B       C       D
1       NULL    20      34      NULL
2       52      27      NULL    NULL
3       20      NULL    22      30
```